# Unable to open datasource 'MySQL' using ogr2ogr

Tags: shapefile, gdal, mysql-spatial

I am trying to dump shapefile data into MySQL using GDAL ogr2ogr command

```
ogr2ogr –f MySQL MySQL:SHP_DB,host=localhost,user=root,password=root feature_object.shp  -nln phil_custom -update -overwrite -lco engine=MYISAM
```

I am getting this error:

  -

```
FAILURE:
Unable to open datasource `MySQL' with the following drivers.
  -> PCIDSK
  -> netCDF
  -> JP2OpenJPEG
  -> PDF
  -> ESRI Shapefile
  -> MapInfo File
  -> UK .NTF
  -> OGR_SDTS
  -> S57
  -> DGN
  -> OGR_VRT
  -> REC
  -> Memory
  -> BNA
  -> CSV
  -> NAS
  -> GML
  -> GPX
  -> LIBKML
  -> KML
  -> GeoJSON
  -> Interlis 1
  -> Interlis 2
  -> OGR_GMT
  -> GPKG
  -> SQLite
  -> OGR_DODS
  -> ODBC
  -> WAsP
  -> PGeo
  -> MSSQLSpatial
  -> OGR_OGDI
  -> PostgreSQL
  -> MySQL
  -> OpenFileGDB
  -> XPlane
  -> DXF
  -> Geoconcept
  -> GeoRSS
  -> GPSTrackMaker
  -> VFK
  -> PGDUMP
  -> OSM
  -> GPSBabel
  -> SUA
  -> OpenAir
  -> OGR_PDS
  -> WFS
  -> HTF
  -> AeronavFAA
  -> Geomedia
  -> EDIGEO
  -> GFT
  -> SVG
  -> CouchDB
  -> Cloudant
  -> Idrisi
  -> ARCGEN
  -> SEGUKOOA
  -> SEGY
  -> XLS
  -> ODS
  -> XLSX
  -> ElasticSearch
  -> Walk
  -> CartoDB
  -> AmigoCloud
  -> SXF
  -> Selafin
  -> JML
  -> PLSCENES
  -> CSW
  -> VDV
  -> TIGER
  -> AVCBin
  -> AVCE00
  -> HTTP
```

I could not find any solution to this error.
What could be the possible cause of this error as I have dump shapefiles data successfully with the same command?

GDAL version is-
GDAL 2.1.0, released 2016/04/25

OS- ubuntu 14.04

---

Comment: What do you get with `ogrinfo MySQL:SHP_DB,host=localhost,user=root,password=root`?

Comment: Usage: ogrinfo [--help-general] [-ro] [-q] [-where restricted_where|@filename]
               [-spat xmin ymin xmax ymax] [-geomfield field] [-fid fid]
               [-sql statement|@filename] [-dialect sql_dialect] [-al] [-so] [-fields={YES/NO}]
               [-geom={YES/NO/SUMMARY}] [-formats] [[-oo NAME=VALUE] ...]
               [-nomd] [-listmdd] [-mdd domain|`all`]*
               [-nocount] [-noextent]
               datasource_name [layer [layer ...]]

FAILURE: No datasource specified.

Comment: Try `ogrinfo MySQL:"SHP_DB,host=localhost,user=root,password=root"`

Comment: It is showing : INFO: Open of `MySQL:SHP_DB,host=localhost,user=root,password=root'
      using driver `MySQL' successful.
But again after running ogr2ogr , i am getting the same error

Answer (score 2):

I changed my syntax from this

```
ogr2ogr –f MySQL MySQL:SHP_DB,host=localhost,user=root,password=root feature_object.shp  -nln phil_custom -update -overwrite -lco engine=MYISAM
```

to this

```
ogr2ogr MySQL:SHP_DB,host=localhost,user=root,password=root feature_object.shp  -nln phil_custom -update -overwrite -lco engine=MYISAM
```

and it worked !! I don't know the reason.

Comment: For some reason GDAL did not understood the "-f MySQL" part of your command. It you have copy-pasted the command the dash character in front of "f" may be some other character that just looks alike. If that is the case it may work if you write that parameter from the keyboard.

Comment: You are correct but I tried that too, wrote whole command myself.

Answer (score 1):

There looks to be syntax differences between an example from BostonGIS and your query

```
ogr2ogr –f MySQL MySQL:SHP_DB,host=localhost,user=root,password=root feature_object.shp  -nln phil_custom -update -overwrite -lco engine=MYISAM
```

Example

```
ogr2ogr -f "MySQL" MYSQL:"mydb,host=myhost,user=mylogin,password=mypassword,port=3306" -nln "world" -a_srs "EPSG:4326" path/to/world_adm0.shp
```

I would attempt running the below:

```
ogr2ogr –f "MySQL" MYSQL:"SHP_DB,host=localhost,user=root,password=root"  -nln "phil_custom" -update -overwrite -lco engine=MYISAM feature_object.shp
```

Answer (score 0):

sometimes if you have used the ' ' in the filename like 'rainfall UK', this error would be happen. But you try to change it as 'rainfall_UK', it would be fine