# converting geojson to shapefile gives error "Unable to Unable to open datasource using following drivers"

Tags: python, shapefile, ogr2ogr, json

Im trying to convert geojson file to shapefile. Below is the code

```
import ogr2ogr
import json


def main():
  #note: main is expecting sys.argv, where the first argument is the script name
  #so, the argument indices in the array need to be offset by 1
  ogr2ogr.main(["","-f","ESRI Shapefile","I:/shapefile/json_output.shp","I:/json_output.json -overwrite engine=GeoJSON"])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I get the following error

```
Unable to open datasource `I:/json_output.json -overwrite engine=GeoJSON' with the following drivers.
  ->  PCIDSK
  ->  netCDF
  ->  JP2ECW
  ->  JP2OpenJPEG
  ->  JPEG2000
  ->  DB2ODBC
  ->  ESRI Shapefile
  ->  MapInfo File
  ->  UK .NTF
  ->  OGR_SDTS
  ->  S57
  ->  DGN
  ->  OGR_VRT
  ->  REC
  ->  Memory
  ->  BNA
  ->  CSV
  ->  GML
  ->  GPX
  ->  LIBKML
  ->  KML
  ->  GeoJSON
  ->  OGR_GMT
  ->  GPKG
  ->  SQLite
  ->  ODBC
  ->  WAsP
  ->  PGeo
  ->  MSSQLSpatial
  ->  PostgreSQL
  ->  OpenFileGDB
  ->  XPlane
  ->  DXF
  ->  Geoconcept
  ->  GeoRSS
  ->  GPSTrackMaker
  ->  VFK
  ->  PGDUMP
  ->  OSM
  ->  GPSBabel
  ->  SUA
  ->  OpenAir
  ->  OGR_PDS
  ->  WFS
  ->  HTF
  ->  AeronavFAA
  ->  Geomedia
  ->  EDIGEO
  ->  GFT
  ->  SVG
  ->  CouchDB
  ->  Cloudant
  ->  Idrisi
  ->  ARCGEN
  ->  SEGUKOOA
  ->  SEGY
  ->  XLS
  ->  ODS
  ->  XLSX
  ->  ElasticSearch
  ->  Walk
  ->  Carto
  ->  AmigoCloud
  ->  SXF
  ->  Selafin
  ->  JML
  ->  PLSCENES
  ->  CSW
  ->  VDV
  ->  TIGER
  ->  AVCBin
  ->  AVCE00
  ->  HTTP
```

I tried the following link
[Unable to open datasource 'MySQL' using ogr2ogr](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/222194/unable-to-open-datasource-mysql-using-ogr2ogr) but no luck. Please help!!

Comment: You have written the input file it literally like that "I:/json_output.json -overwrite engine=GeoJSON". And what is that "engine=GeoJSON"?

Comment: Even when I write ogr2ogr.main(["","-f","ESRI Shapefile","I:/shapefile/json_output.shp","I:/json_output.json"]) I get the same error

Comment: Test the syntax from command line until it works. Edit then your script to create a similar command. Your aim is `ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" I:/shapefile/json_output.shp I:/json_output.json`. BTW this question does not seem to have anything to do with GIS, just plain Python.